# What is wrong with this C code? First it asks for 2 integers , but it should ask only 1 and after i put the 2 integers it crashes

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int i , j , n;
    printf("Give a natural integer : ");
    scanf("%d " , &n);
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) {
        for ( j = 1 ; j <= i ; j++) {
            scanf("%d " , j );
        }
        printf(" \n ");
    }

}
```

Where from does it  take the second input?
Why it crashes?

Comment: It is crashing because of this: `scanf("%d " , j )`. First of all it should take pointer, not an integer. Second - it is not clear what it is supposed to achieve.

Comment: And then, the input is changing the loop condition. `j ` controls the loop.

Comment: I think OP wanted to put `printf()`

Comment: "First it asks for 2 integers , but it should ask only 1 " problem is because of the space in `"%d "` --> drop the space.

Comment: What is an "un-**natural** integer"? A zombie-integer?

Answer (score 1):

Notice anything missing here?

```
        scanf("%d " , j );
                     ^---
```

like a `&`, perhaps?

`scanf()` expects a pointer for the second argument, so it knows where to write the scanned value(s). You're not passing a pointer, you're passing an integer, so scanf() receives whatever random number is in that var (since you never initialized it) and uses that number as a pointer, causing your crash.

Answer (score 1):

Change your first scanf to:

```
/* scanf("%d " , &n); */
scanf("%d" , &n); // no space after %d
```

Also, most probably you wanted to using `printf` inside the loops:

```
/* scanf("%d " , j ); */
printf("%d " , j );
```

If at all you wanted to do `scanf` inside the loop:

```
 /* scanf("%d " , j ); */
 scanf("%d" , &j ); // no space after %d; and add & before j
```

Not related to `scanf`, but your main should be returning `int`, not `void`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `scanf("%d " , j );` *you need* `printf("%d ", j);`in inner loop.

Comment: There is a missing `&` in `scanf`.

Comment: @haccks Yes , but I would rather say is `scanf` needed . OP is aksing why  program is asking for second input . So probably he doesn't want `scanf`. He wanted `pritnf` and assuming `printf` he did not put `&` , which caused problem as it was `scanf`. So, I addressed that  :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your nested `for` loops, you call `scanf("%d " , j );` You need to pass the address of `j` into `scanf`.

```
scanf("%d " , &j );
```